# page.exposeFunction with Chrome DevTools Protocol?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

How can I implement `page.exposeFunction` from puppeteer
with Chrome DevTools Protocol? I checked the sourcecode of puppeteer but was not able to understand it.